# Moodle flexible_table sorting

Tags: php, moodle

I am using `Moodle 2.6` and already rewrote a table from `html_table` to `flexible_table`. I could not figure out, how the `sorting` is working.
I set everything as follows:

```
$table = new flexible_table('Car Bookings');
            $table->define_baseurl(new moodle_url("/blocks/cars/view.php"));
                $table->define_columns(array(
                    'carname',
                    'platenumber',
                    'pickupdate',
                    'tankdate',
                    'city', 
                    'actions',
                ));
            $table->define_headers(array(
                    'car name',
                    'plate number',
                    'pick-up date',
                    'tank date',
                    'city', 
                    'actions',
                ));
            $table->sortable(true, 'carname');
            $table->collapsible(false);
```

I then add for the sorting:

```
    if ($table->get_sql_sort()) {
        $sort = ' ORDER BY '.$table->get_sql_sort();
    } else {
        $sort = '';
    }
```

The table is rendering, but the sorting is not working, i.e the headers are "sorting"-I can click on them, but nothing happens. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the sorting manually. Something like this:

```
if ($orderby = $table->get_sql_sort()) {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . $orderby . ' ';
}
```

Have a look at the code in `/user/index.php`

Comment: Hi Russel, they are using htlm_table there and I flexible_table

Comment: In Moodle 2.6.11, around line 257 in `/user/index.php` it has `$table = new flexible_table('user-index-participants-'.$course->id);`

Comment: Hi Russel, i put in my tableif `($table->get_sql_sort()) {
    $sort = ' ORDER BY '.$table->get_sql_sort();
} else {
    $sort = '';
}` from user/index.ph but It still wont sort the columns. What I am doing wrong?